# Why is ParametricPlot3D not producing a graph

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

I have the vector **V = {2, y z^2, 3 y + z**}

I wanted to get a 3d parametric plot of V using: `x[t] = Sin[t^2]; y[t] = t^2 - Cos[t]; z[t] = Sinh[t] - Cos[t]`. So I did:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 x, y z^2, 3 y + z}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

I am unsure what to take for the fx argument inside ParametricPlot3d as x=2 inside V. I decided to go for what I did as shown above. And I do not get a graph at all.

Comment: use `Evaluate@{2 x[t], y[t] z[t]^2, 3 y[t] + z[t]}` instead of `{2 x, y z^2, 3 y + z}`?

Comment: As ParametricPlot3D[ { fx, fy, fz},{u,umin,umax} ] takes this general form, can you tell me if by taking 2x for fx I did the right thing? Or should I have left it as 2 inside ParametricPlot3D?
I also used Evaluate inside PP3D but plot is still empty.

Comment: `Block[{x = Sin[t^2], y = t^2 - Cos[t], z = Sinh[t] - Cos[t], 
  V = {2 x, y z^2, 3 y + z}}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[V, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]]`

Comment: Btw one thing I am confused about is if the x-variable is a constant like 2 here inside V where V = {2, y z^2, 3 y + z} then does it affect ParametricPlot3D or do i have to always parameterize any constant for plotting in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function `V[t]` uses `x[t],y[t],z[t]` (okay x is not used but anyways) I would define them first using this code:

```
x[t_] = Sin[t^2];
y[t_] = t^2 - Cos[t];
z[t_] = Sinh[t] - Cos[t];
```

Now you can define `V[t]` itself

```
V[t_] = {2, y[t]*z[t]^2, 3*y[t] + z[t]};
```

We can now use `ParametricPlot3D` :

```
ParametricPlot3D[
   V[t], 
   {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
   PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}
]
```

Now you will get plot which looks quite awkward because Mathematica chooses the plotRange on its own so I added `PlotRange` to make a more pleasing looking plot:

[image]

You might need to adjust the values in the `PlotRange` to your desire.

Comment: Yes, it worked, was my plot command then not working because I did not define the functions? That's the difference I am seeing. 
Another thing I want to ask is that if I want to calculate the divergence of this vector V[t] then would Div[V[t], {x[t], y[t], z[t]}] work although this just returns me the divergence*V - not any actual expression or value. Is it possible or should the original V expression  V = {2, y z^2, 3 y + z} be only evaluated for divergence?

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

x[t] = Sin[t^2]; y[t] = t^2 - Cos[t]; z[t] = Sinh[t] - Cos[t];
```

The functions must include their arguments and since the functions are literally only defined for the symbol `t` you must `Evaluate` them prior to `t` being assigned any numeric values.

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@{2 x[t], y[t] z[t]^2, 3 y[t] + z[t]},
 {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

The usual way to define functions is with a pattern as the argument

```
Clear["Global`*"]

x[t_] = Sin[t^2]; y[t_] = t^2 - Cos[t]; z[t_] = Sinh[t] - Cos[t];
```

In this case the `Evaluate` is not needed.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {2 x[t], y[t] z[t]^2, 3 y[t] + z[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

< same image >